# Stack Overflow Forbidden

Tags: support, 403-forbidden

Stack Overflow has been giving me this error today and it didn't before. Did they have an issue or make a change forbidding users?

[image]

Comment: Why does your browser think the the connection is not secure?  Maybe it is having a problem with a certificate?

Comment: Check the certificate information and post it. Sounds like MITM.

Comment: Most likely your ISP is playing tricks. My advise: find other ISP, ASAP.